# Java Game Development - Assets getting cut off at edges of screen?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a game using only java (no libraries at all), but I'm having an issue with the rendering where assets that I'm drawing to the screen get cut off at the edges of the screen. When I set the window JFrame to be undecorated it fixes the issue, but I obviously can't have the window be undecorated.

I'm doing something like this to render assets:

```
g.drawImage(asset.getImage(), 0, HEIGHT - asset.getImage().getHeight(), Main.getInstance());
```

Where g is the graphics instance, HEIGHT is the height of the window, and where Main extends Canvas. My issue is that I have to subtract a constant from this in order for the bottom of the asset not to get cut off. However, when I set the frame to be undecorated the above code works fine. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Where from do you take the Graphics Object? The JFrame or its root- or content pane? The JFrame is the whole thing, including the title-bar as you noticed. If you really want just to draw inside the JFrame you should get the Graphics from the mentioned panes or add a JPanel to the JFrame and use this JPanel's Graphics object. Then the dimensions should be fine.

Comment: I'm getting the graphics object from the buffer strategy of the main class which extends Canvas. This is the render method: BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
  if (bs == null)
  {
   createBufferStrategy(3);
   return;
  }

  Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();